# Trying to create mask to eliminate false NDVI numbers in GEE time series analysis using Sentinel data

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, sentinel-2, time-series, masking

It keeps given me the error that ndvi.gte is not a function, I shared my code below:

```
var images = sentinel.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate,endDate)).filterBounds(geometry)
print(images);

var ndvi = function(image){
  var ndv = image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
  return ndv.copyProperties(image,['system:index', 'system:time_start'])
}
var ndvi = images.map(ndvi);


print(ndvi);

var nd = ndvi.first().clip(geometry);
Map.addLayer(nd,{min:0,max:1,palette:['white','Green']},'NDVI');

//Add Mask
var maskedNDVI = ndvi.gte(0.25);
var maskedNDVI = ndvi.updateMask(maskNDVI);
Map.addLayer(maskedNDVI,{min: 0, max: 1}, 'NDVI');

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
imageCollection: ndvi,
  regions:geometry4,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 250
});
print(chart);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply a threshold in image collection you must implement function in map loop. Here is corrected code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/92372c02aa57eab5acac372e12c7997d

Comment: Thank you for you answer it was really helpful! What I actually try to do is eliminating missing mixels by temporal gap filling with linear interpolation to get a smooth result from my model. Do you happen to have any recommendations on how to adapt my model further to realise this?

Comment: There is a tutorial for regression gap filling in google earth engine that I have used in my projects:
https://spatialthoughts.com/2021/11/08/temporal-interpolation-gee/

Comment: Please accept the answer, you mentioned that is corrected.